# Can I test ES2015 (‘ES6’) code without transpiling it?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have found [a lot of tutorials](http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/) for testing ES2015 code by transpiling it (with Babel) to ES5 and then testing the ES5 code. But is there any test framwork that can test code using native ES2015 features (like default arguments) without transpiling it?

It seems quite strange having to install a whole transpiler setup only for test coverage. I wonder if there is a native way to do assertions on ES2015 code.

Comment: There is a way. Test it in a browser that supports ES6 features used in the app. Which will be quite difficult to do for ES6 modules, because they aren't supported by browsers. Please, improve the question by stating used testing tools. Some of them (e.g. Karma) offer seamless setups for transpilation.

Comment: "*a whole tranpiler setup* only *for test coverage*" - if you don't need a transpiler for the actual build, you don't need it for test coverage either. If you need it for the build anyway, you'll need it for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a question of the testing framework, but rather of the javascript environment. If your engine does natively support the ES6 features that your tests are using, then you can run the framework and your tests natively. Node 6 does quite a good job at this already, [there's only a few things missing](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) (most importantly, modules). Just don't install a transpiler and it will still work.

Of course, there are a few features that are not yet supported, and also there are a lot of environments that have no ES6 support in general, but all the test frameworks do want to support them (or needed to support them in the past). So that's why the transpiler *as an option* is (still) built into the whole tool chain - even when you don't necessarily have to use it any more these days.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Node 6 supports [most of ES2015 features](http://node.green). Alternatively, you can use a runner, like [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/), to run tests in any modern browser with good [ES2015 support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).